# While working with selenium, an error showed which was saying that 'import "selenium" couldn't be resolved.'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I dont' find a problem in my code and it is showing another problem which is - :

driver = webdriver.Chrome(excutable_path='C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe')
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'excutable_path'

```
   import openpyxl as xl
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(excutable_path='C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe')

wb = xl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx')
sheet_1 = wb["Sheet1"]
cell_1 = sheet_1["b2"]
cell_2 = sheet_1["c2"]
cell_3 = sheet_1["d2"]
cell_4 = sheet_1["d2"]

driver.get('http://ritulpatwa.com/')

name = driver.find_element_by_name('na')
name.send_keys(cell_1)
name.send_keys(keys.RETURN)

mail = driver.find_element_by_name('em')
mail.send_keys(cell_2)
mail.send_keys(keys.RETURN)

phone = driver.find_element_by_name('ph')
phone.send_keys(cell_3)
phone.send_keys(keys.RETURN)

query = driver.find_element_by_name('quer')
query.send_keys(cell_4)
query.send_keys(keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: The word is ex**e**cutable, not excutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `excutable_path` instead of `executable_path`.

try something like this :

```
executable_path = r"C:\\etc\\Inc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path)
```